# Why an unstable particle is not the exact eigenstate of the exact hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

According to Srednicki's QFT textbook, page151
"According to our development of LSZ formula in section5, each incoming and outgoing particle should correspond to a single-particle state that is an exact eigenstate of the exact hamiltonian. This is clearly not the case for a particle that can decay."

Why an unstable particle is not the exact eigenstate of the exact hamiltonian? Because its eigenvalue of the full hamiltonian is the $m_\phi$. Where is my fault?

Comment: A particle decays due to some interactions with the vacuum, hence the Hamiltonian has a perturbative term. You need to apply interacting field theory here, and the particles are not exact energy eigenstates.

Comment: An eigenstate is stationary, it changes only by an overall phase over time. If a particle decays, the late time system is instead in a totally different state, therefore the decaying particle can't possibly be an exact hamiltonian eigenstate

Comment: @TwoBs Then how to explian 2-particle collision? The 2-particle state most be the exact eigenstate of the exact hamiltonian.

Comment: @user34669 The system of two-particle states, defined say by two separate 4-momentum at very early (or very late) times, is eigenstate of the system only for $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$, not for a finite time $t$. On the contrary, the $|in\rangle$ or $|out\rangle$ states are exact eigenstates

Comment: @TwoBs The system of two-particle states, defined say by two separate 4-momentum at very early (or very late) times, is not the |in⟩ state? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @TwoBs I'm confused about several concepts of QFT. If the $|in \rangle$ state is the eigensate of the full hamiltonian then why it can change to the $|out\rangle$ state?

Comment: As I said,the difference is that one is eigenstate whereas the other is not (although, they match more and more as the interactions fall off at $t\rightarrow\pm\infty$).

Comment: @user34669 One actually scatters wave packets which are not eigenstates. The matching between in/out and the free waves is at the level of wave packets. Mathematically the difference between in/out states boils down to the $\pm i\epsilon$ that is needed to switch-off interactions at $\pm\infty$. There is a nice description in Weinberg, sec.3.1 volume I.

Comment: @TwoBs I think you should make your comment an answer.