# Is resonance an energy eigenstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, schroedinger-equation, scattering, resonance

In the particle physics book of Martin & Shaw, they used QM to derive the decay distribution, namely, breit wigner formula.
What confused me was that, here they assumed the resonance state $\psi_0 $ is an energy eigenstate with energy $E_0$.

But in another quesion of mine 
[Does the Breit–Wigner formula indicate "violation" of energy conservation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489691/does-the-breit-wigner-formula-indicate-violation-of-energy-conservation/489854#489854)
@anna v suggested that the resonance does not have a definite mass. Hence it can't be an energy eigenstate. This seems to be a contradiction.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A much better discussion can be found in C. P. Burgess and G. D. Moore. The standard model: A primer. Cambridge University Press, 2006. The above one is very confusing IMHO.

Comment: Resonance doesn't have any definite mass, so it cannot be an energy eigenstate.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118780/why-an-unstable-particle-is-not-the-exact-eigenstate-of-the-exact-hamiltonian).

Comment: An unstable state of the type you are considering is a *quasi-stationary state* (or metastable such) with *complex* energy eigenvalue $E=E_0-i\Gamma/2$ , best detailed in Landau & Lifschitz QM, §134. Yes, the Hamiltonian has schematic, approximate, effective nonhermitean terms, but for sufficiently short times (compared to the lifetime) the scheme works.

Comment: If there is an large uncertainty in the energy of short lived particle, then why can we treat very short lived particle like Higgs or Z as external lines in Feynman diagram?

Comment: you mean why do you call them external when their decay renders them internal?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I mean sometimes we can calculate, for example, the decay rate of Z. In such case, Z appears as external lines so it must has a real energy and be on-shell. If there is always an uncertainty in its energy, namely, if it's always an off-shell virtual particle, how can this be done?

Comment: Maybe you wish to consider QFT. You start with a real energy Z as described in the lagrangian, and compute its width. Now, in a calculation where it is internal, you use the calculated width in the energy, etc... in an effective action. Alternatively, and equivalently, you stick to the tree value, real energy, and compute  1,2,... loops in your internal Z amp. That's why QFT is superior. It accounts for everything without philosophical conundrums.